Text Gradient Animation Effect On NET8 MAUI?
Is it possible to have text gradient effect like HTML5 CSS3 on NET8 MAUI?
I have file CSS:
.NameClassHTML{
    font-size: 39px;
    font-style:normal;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, rgb(245, 66, 78), rgb(66, 245, 147),             
    rgb(66, 129, 245)) 0% 0% / 300% 300%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    animation: 2s linear 0s infinite normal none running fontgradient;
    -webkit-animation: fontgradient 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: fontgradient 2s linear infinite;
    animation: fontgradient 2s linear infinite;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes fontgradient {
    0%{background-position:0% 92%}
    50%{background-position:100% 9%}
    100%{background-position:0% 92%}
}
@-moz-keyframes fontgradient {
    0%{background-position:0% 92%}
    50%{background-position:100% 9%}
    100%{background-position:0% 92%}
}
@keyframes fontgradient { 
    0%{background-position:0% 92%}
    50%{background-position:100% 9%}
    100%{background-position:0% 92%}
}
.divNameClass{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:#121212;
    padding: 1em; font-weight: bold;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius:39px;
}

HTML like this:
<div class="divNameClass">
    <label class="NameClassHTML">Hello World!</label>
</div>

For me, the text animation gradient pattern is very beautiful. But I don't know how to have this effect on NET8 MAUI. I know it is possible to use WebView.. But WebView has too many limitations. So that is a bad option.

You can check this link about the Gradients.

You may also try using SkiaSharp linear gradient.
